# Index English language item version only

Tags: solr

I have two versions of every item (English and Chinese).

While indexing, I have noticed both the versions (English and Chinese) of every item is indexed.

How can I only index the English version.

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can refer this link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/why-does-my-solr-index-only-contain-english-language-versions-sitecore-8u4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible OOTB but you can perform this by creating your custom crawler by inheriting the OOTB crawler (This customization is not recommended for Sitecore's OOTB indexes i.e sitecore_master_index, sitecore_web_index and sitecore_core_index.)

I have given a similar answer for creating a separate index for each language also you can modify this code a little for excluding some of languages from indexing - [Sitecore Index - Separate index for each language](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23444/sitecore-index-separate-index-for-each-language)